# regex_search trying to match a string containing '['

Tags: regex, c++14

Being relatively new to regular expressions I am having trouble figuring out the correct syntax. I am trying to match a string with the following pattern: String[string]!='string'. I want to divide it into three matches as it follows:

1. String[string] // can contain numbers
2. != // operator that can also be: =,> and < or a combination of these
3. 'string' // can contain _ and numbers

So far I have managed to match a string with the following pattern: string='string'. Using this code:

```
const string strExpression = "TypeValue!='Set_Site'";
regex regex("([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([=><!]+)(['a-zA-Z0-9_]+)");
smatch match;
if (regex_search(strExpression.begin(), strExpression.end(), match, regex)) 
{
    string indicator(match[1]);
    string op(match[2]);
    string value(match[3]);
}
```

However when I try to add '[' and ']' to the regex syntax I don't get any matches. I have modified the code like this:

```
const string strExpression = "Type[Value]!='Set_Site'";
regex regex("([]a-zA-Z0-9[]+)([=><!]+)(['a-zA-Z0-9_]+)");
smatch match;
if (regex_search(strExpression.begin(), strExpression.end(), match, regex)) 
{
    string indicator(match[1]);
    string op(match[2]);
    string value(match[3]);
}
```

Аccording to the documentation I am reading the right-square-bracket ( ']' ) will lose its special meaning (terminating the bracket expression) and represent itself in a bracket expression if it occurs first in the list. For the left-square-bracket( '[' ) it says that it will lose its special meaning within a bracket expression. So following this rules and definitions I cannot identify why i am not getting any matches

Can someone give me some guidelines what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: try `string\[string\] (?:op1|op2|op3) 'string'` and flesh it out a bit.

Comment: And I suggest not reading the docs about escaping rules for `[]`. If you need to find litersls, escape them no matter where they are.

Comment: It seems sln's suggestion is right: `regex regex("([\\]a-zA-Z0-9[]+)([=><!]+)(['a-zA-Z0-9_]+)");` works, though this violates the usual rules for regexps.  Usually your original solution is right, and quoting would introduce a '\' into the character class.

Comment: Apparently C++ uses the same regex syntax as ECMAScript.  See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/